# How to return an array of dynamic xpaths in typescript?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I have a set of xpaths that need arguments to select the proper element. However the below method doesn't seem to work.

```
async returnSection(sectionName: string, childItem: string): Promise<WebElement> {

        let selectedSection = element(by.xpath(`//div[@class='default-name info' and text()='${sectionName}']`));
        let aChildItem = element(by.xpath(`//div[@class='default-name' and text()='${childItem}']`));
        let customName = element(by.xpath(`//div[@class='default-name' and text()='${childItem}']/../../../..//input[@placeholder='None']`));
        let pageObjects: WebElement[] = [selectedSection, aChildItem, customName];
        // return pageObjects[] //I am not able to return this array.

    }
```

I would eventually use the returned value like:

```
abc = returnSection("1","2");
element1 = abc[0];
element2 = abc[1];
```

Or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

> // return pageObjects[] //I am not able to return this array.

You have the return type annotated as `Promise<WebElement>`, but you want to return an array of `WebElement`.

## Fix

Change

```
async returnSection(sectionName: string, childItem: string): Promise<WebElement> {
```

To

```
async returnSection(sectionName: string, childItem: string): Promise<WebElement[]> {
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked :) But I found a better way to handle my situation. Maybe useful for others who will get into a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but if not handled properly, a lot of undefined will occur. Moreover debugging on VSCode will be so much more easier with this approach.

To handle a situation like this, the approach has to be changed. Instead of returning an array of WebElements, return the string of xpaths like so.

```
    useBenefits(sectionName: string, childItemName: string): string[] {
        let benefitSection = `//div[@class='default-name info' and text()='${sectionName}']`;
        let childItem = `//div[@class='default-name' and text()='${childItemName}']`;
        let customText = `//div[@class='default-name' and text()='${childItem}']/../../../..//input[@placeholder='None']`;
        return new Array(benefitSection, childItem, customText);
    }
```

Now use this call this function by passing parameters and store them in an array. Use the array elements as xpaths for a WebElement.

```
    let abc1: string[] = this.expertPIAHelper.useSectionBenefits('Achievement', "Confidence");
        let section = element(by.xpath(abc1[0]));
        let child = element(by.xpath(abc1[1]));
        let custom = element(by.xpath(abc1[2]));
        await this.helper.click(section);
        await browser.sleep(1000);
        await this.helper.enterText(custom, "Custom Name");
        await browser.sleep(1000);
        await this.helper.click(this.selectedBenefitSection);
        await browser.sleep(1000);
```

Makes code maintenance and debugging a whole lot easier.